# mobile devices under Mac Os X to connect to Docker

Tags: docker, device

I'm trying to connect to my docker instance the devices I have connected to my laptop.

Concretely I have 4 devices (two iphones, two android) and I would like to be able to start 4 docker instances and connect each device to one instance.

What I expected to do is as simply as in ubuntu

```
docker run --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -d -P my-android:0.0.1
```

But my host OS is a Mac OS X, also the instances I'm creating, because I need access to the instruments tool.

but so far I read that under mac os x, devices are connected directly though usb not being mounted.

this is what I got when I search for the iphone device:

```
      iPhone USB:
      Type: Ethernet
      BSD Device Name: en6
      IPv4:
          Configuration Method: DHCP
      IPv6:
          Configuration Method: Automatic
      Proxies:
          Exceptions List: *.local, 169.254/16
          FTP Passive Mode: Yes
```

Do you know how can I connect the devices to the docker instances?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: same problem here... wish I could forward /dev/bus/usb to use Linux's version of adb and fastboot with my Android, via Docker...

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with the [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) on [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with the VirtualBox Extension Pack installed (provides support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices).

- have the mobile phone connected to the host system.

  ```
  $ ioreg -p IOUSB | grep SAMSUNG
  +-o SAMSUNG_Android@14100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000c66, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (13 ms), retain 34>
  ```
- create the a docker machine with the virtualbox driver (I've named it
  `base`)

  ```
  docker-machine create --driver virtualbox base
  ```
- stop the machine to enable the USB Controller on the VM

  ```
  docker-machine stop base
  ```

[image: Enable USB Controller]

```
    docker-machine start base
```

- activate the `base` VM as docker host

```
    eval $(docker-machine env base)
```

- start ubuntu container with the usb devices mounted

```
    docker run -it --rm -v /dev/usb/bus:/dev/bus/usb ubuntu /bin/bash
```

- install the `usbutils` just to demo with `lsusb` that the android device is connected

```
    root@ce1e4be0bb73:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y usbutils
```

- 1st run of `lsusb` (did not show the device)

  ```
  root@ce1e4be0bb73:/# lsusb
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```
- to show the device I had to unplug and plug again my phone, 2nd run of `lsusb`

  ```
  root@ce1e4be0bb73:/# lsusb
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```